# R foreach parallel can not find global function

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, lapply

I try to replace `lapply` function with parallel `foreach`.
I have two functions:

```
 dRet <- function(x,per,sloss,daysToReopt){
 ...
 }
 getSum <- function(curEnv,perTP){
  ...
  dRetlst <- function(x) return(dRet(x,perTP,sl,days))
  Es_1 <- lapply(stlst,dRetlst)
  Es_2 <- foreach(a = stlst) %do% dRetlst(a)
  ...
 }
```

`perTp,sl,days`- are constant.

`stlst` is list of lists (of xts).

If I do this way, everything will be OK (`Es_1` equal to `Es_2`).

I have replaced `getSum` function:

```
getSum <- function(curEnv,perTP){
 ...
 dRetlst <- function(x) return(dRet(x,perTP,sl,days))
 cl<-makeCluster(2)
 registerDoParallel(cl)
 #registerDoSNOW(cl)
 Es_2 <- foreach(a = stlst) %dopar% dRetlst(a)
 stopCluster(cl)
 ...
}
```

As a result, I had error: `Error in dRetlst(a) : 
  task 1 failed - "can not find function "dRet""`

How can i solve this problem without adding `dRet` into `getSum`?

(R version 3.1.2, Windows 8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the foreach `.export` option to explicitly export `dRet` to the workers:

```
Es_2 <- foreach(a = stlst, .export='dRet') %dopar% dRetlst(a)
```

Also, I think the foreach loop would be more readable as:

```
Es_2 <- foreach(a = stlst, .export='dRet') %dopar% {
    dRet(a,perTP,sl,days)
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for your answer, and also for your package!